# Regular expression integer with jquery and test() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Regular Expression: `/^[1-9][0-9]*$/`

The regexp works as intended on http://www.phpliveregex.com

My problem is that it doesn't work when implemented with JS, see my code on http://jsfiddle.net/LHHU7

The JS:

```
$("#mytextbox").on("keypress", function(event) {

var re = /^[1-9][0-9]*$/;
var key = doKey(arguments[0] || window.event);
var char = String.fromCharCode(key);

if (key == 8 || key == 37 || key == 39 || re.test(char)) {
    return true;
}

return false;
});

$('#mytextbox').on("paste",function(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
});

function doKey(event) {
var key = event.keyCode | event.charCode;
return key;
}
```

Test cases expected:
    `0001       fail`
    `11 11      fail`
    `1000       success`
    `1264       success`
    `5001       success`

What's happening with my code:
`0001       fail WORKING`
`11 11      fail WORKING`
`1000       success NOT WORKING`
`1264       success WORKING`
`5001       success NOT WORKING`

For some reason 0 won't be entered. I've already tried on chrome, with no success. I've tried changing my RegExp multiple times with no different results. I've also tried different implementations on my code, but still no success.

Please see if you can get it working on my jsfiddle before posting your answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only checking a single character (the latest one) against the regex, when you probably really want to match the content of the textbox + the character. This makes it impossible to enter a zero at all, since it will always be matched against `^[1-9]`.

Matching the existing textbox value + the character should work better;

```js
if (key == 8 || key == 37 || key == 39 ||     
      re.test(document.getElementById("mytextbox").value + char)) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I feel so stupid now that I look at my code again. Guess I'm more tired than I thought.
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As @Joachim Isaksson mentioned, you are only looking at the last character so your regex is wrong. Update regex to:

```
var re = /^[0-9]$/;
```

This will match one number, 0-9.

Comment: Don't want my first digit being a 0 :P

Answer (score 0):

Edit the Following to your code it works fine [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LHHU7/14/)

```
var testString=$('#mytextbox').val();
    if (key == 8 || key == 37 || key == 39 || re.test(testString + char) )
```